# Changing the direction of slider's\carousel's navigation-arrows?

Tags: slider, right-to-left

Given we have a slider and the site is Right-to-left.

The slider's arrows work the other way around (Left points right and vice versa).

What  are the plausible places to look for the problem in the devtool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution is a pure-css one and deals particularly with the Flexslider library. It's an RTLization of a particular code-piece of the main Flexslider's CSS file. The site itself is Drupal-based so the path is: `/public_html/yoursitesname/sites/all/libraries/flexslider`. If your site is not Drupal-based just track the path of the flexslider library and apply the solution there. Here are the stages:

1. copied this piece (which I'll present in a sec), in a note: `/*Syntax*/` for backup for future times.
2. RTLizied the original piece.
3. It should be noted that the last part of the RTLization process was to replace between `content:'\f001'`; and `content:'\f002'`. I note this because it's less intuitive than changes like flipping a `"left:#px"` to a `"right:#px"` one...
4. Gave to the existing query (see end of flexslider.css):

> @media screen and (max-width: 860px)
>       {
>       .flex-direction-nav .flex-prev { opacity: 1; left: auto;}
>       .flex-direction-nav .flex-next { opacity: 1; right: auto;}
>       }

Instead of:

> @media screen and (max-width: 860px) { .flex-direction-nav .flex-prev
>   { opacity: 1; left: 10px;} .flex-direction-nav .flex-next { opacity:
>   1; right: 10px;} }

Enjoy, Ben.